# SQLAlchemy Expression Language first or one

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using the sqlalchemy expression language (i.e. Core). I'm trying to build a query that should only return one result.

I want to do

```
query = select([table]).where(cond).one()
```

or

```
query = select([table]).where(cond).first()
```

but that only yields

```
AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'one'
```

The closest I have come is

```
query = select([table]).where(cond).limit(1)
```

but that is not entirely satisfactory because I get a list of results where I want a single result. I can work around by inserting extra logic but I'd be much happier to find a way to do this cleanly. I also would prefer not  to use plain text queries.

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: `query = select([table]).where(cond).first()` should work without throwing that error and return 1 row. You can also try [`fetchone`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.fetchone)

Comment: Iget the following if I try that:
AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'first'

Answer (score 1):

`one` and `first` are methods available on ORM query objects. On closer inspection you can see that they cause execution of the query and then post process to get get the first/only entry and error check etc.

The SQL dialects that I have checked actually don't seem to have this functionality inbuilt for queries (oops I thought they did). They have `limit` or something similar.

The only option is to work around using `limit` and some logic or some call to execute or on the result.